# My android phone is stuck and won’t boot past its logo

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, recovery-mode, boot, reboot, sony-xperia

After I root my phone to uninstall some not used apps, my phone failed to reboot and stuck, 
it seems that I uninstall some system apps by mistake.
my phone model is sony Xperia t2 and my android version 5.2 
how can I fix that ?
note that the power button is not working on my phone

Answer (score 0):

if your phone is still able to display boot logo, that's a good sign that the bootloader wasn't corrupted;I suppose that you accidentally removed a program ("init", "surface flinger", ...) necessary for booting the user space environment.

I guess you're still able to boot into bootloader mode; if so, just load a fresh firmware (a.k.a ROM).

Comment: and how to load a firmware ?

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials out there, here is one for Xperia T2 Ultra [trueandroid.com](http://trueandroid.com/en/update-sony-xperia-t2-ultra-to-android-5-1-1-lollipop-with-custom-rom-crdroid/). Be careful when performing those steps, you can end up with a bricked phone. best of luck!!

Comment: How are things going for you!! you restored your phone yet!!